# Figure numbering in appendix of a chapter of a book

Tags: appendices, books

So, I am having this issue with figure numbers on an appendix of each chapter of a book. The numbering just goes crazy for the appendix. I have tried several commands to number the appendix different, but the rest of the document just goes crazy. Below a picture illustrating and describing the problem, as well as a MWE.

**The problem**

[image]

The appendix picture numbering just gets a number. I would like for the appendix of the first chapter to number figures as: 1.1A, 1.2A 1.3A And then for the appendix of the second chapter: 2.1A, 2.2A. Ideally without messing the rest of the figure numberings.

**Minimal Working Example (I removed the preamble but I can include it)**

*The main file:*

```
    \documentclass[12pt,letterpaper, notitlepage]{report}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
    \usepackage{har2nat}
    \usepackage{changepage}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{placeins}
    \usepackage{bbm}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{pbox}
    \usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,margin=\parindent,tableposition=top]{caption}
    \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
    \usepackage{datetime}
    \usepackage{epsfig}
    \usepackage{epstopdf}
    \usepackage{bm}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{soul}
    \usepackage[toc, page]{appendix}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{bibentry}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}

    \onehalfspacing
    \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}
    \setlength{\textwidth}{6.7in}
    \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.15in}
    \setlength{\textheight}{8.1in}

    \pagestyle{plain}
    \setlength{\parskip}{.0in}
    \newcommand{\figref}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
    \newcommand{\tabref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}}
    \newcommand{\secref}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}
    \newcommand{\eqnref}[1]{equation (\ref{#1})}
    \newcommand{\chapref}[1]{Chapter~\ref{#1}}

    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
    \titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalsize\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection.}{1em}{}
    \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{11pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{11pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
    \titleformat{\subsection}{\normalsize\itshape\filcenter}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}
    \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{11pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{11pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

    \titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\itshape}{\thesubsubsection.}{1em}{}
    \titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{11pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{11pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
    \newdateformat{monthyeardate}{%
    \monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}
    \useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
    \def\code#1{\texttt{#1}}
    \newcommand\cites[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s\ (\citeyear{#1})}
    \AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}A}}


\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\include{TextPaper1}
\include{figures_Paper1}
\include{Paper1_Appendix}
\pagebreak
\FloatBarrier
\clearpage

\include{TextPaper2}
\include{figures_Paper2}
\pagebreak
\FloatBarrier
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

*The first chapter files:*

```
\chapter{Chapter 1}

Hello World

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{Figure 1 Main text}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{test-figure.png}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{Figure 2 Main Text}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{test-figure.png}}
\end{figure}


\begin{appendices}


\pagebreak
\FloatBarrier
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Figure 1 Appendix}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{test-figure.png}}
\end{figure}


\end{appendices}
```

*The second chapter files*:

```
\chapter{Chapter 2}

Hello World 2 

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{Figure 3 Main text}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{test-figure.png}}
\end{figure}
```

And here's a test figure:

[image]

Comment: you could make a mwe that we could run by making it all one file (you presumably don't need `\include` to show the  issue? and using `example-image` as the image in each case (a test image made available for this kind of test)

Comment: unrelated but `\makebox`  has no effect in `\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{figure3.png}}`

Comment: The figure numbering that you ask about is completely determined by `% Some preamble that I removed`  which makes it impossible to guess what the issue is without following the dropbox link (which should not be necessary)

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I have included the full preamble and made it all one file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the includes above, actually seem to matter a lot for the answer. See answer below.

Comment: include  places `\clearpage` before and after the included material but otherwise should act as if it was one file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below achieves the figure numbering you are after.

There are two important pieces to this code.  First, I added a hook using `etoolbox` to change the figure numbering. Second, I include a `\chapter{..}` command after `\begin{appendices}`. This second step produces a chapter style heading for your appendix and it saves the last value of the chapter counter so that you don't get 0 for the chapter number.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}  % <=== add this

\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}A}}  % <=== add this

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\chapter{Introduction}
Here we have figures \ref{fig:1} and \ref{fig:2}.

\begin{figure}
\caption{First Figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Second Figure}\label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{Appendix to Chapter 1} %<=== add this to get title and non-zero chapter counter
Here we have appendix figures \ref{fig:a1} and \ref{fig:a2}.

\begin{figure}
\caption{First Appendix First Figure}\label{fig:a1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Second Appendix Second Figure}\label{fig:a2}
\end{figure}

\end{appendices}


\chapter{Conclusion}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Second Chapter Figure}\label{fig:3}
\end{figure}

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{Appendix to Chapter 2}
Here we have appendix figures \ref{fig:a3} and \ref{fig:a4}.

\begin{figure}
\caption{Second Appendix Second Figure}\label{fig:a3}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Second Appendix Second Figure}\label{fig:a4}
\end{figure}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

If you do not wish to include the `\chapter{..}` command in the appendix, the following hook will still put the chapter number into your figure number:

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{%
   \setcounter{figure}{0}%
   \renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{@ppsavesec}.\arabic{figure}A}%
}

\makeatother
```

This resets the figure counter to restart in the appendix and it uses the counter in which the `appendices` environment has saved the chapter number. If I put this into the earlier code and delete the `\chapter{..}` commands from the appendices, the result is:
[image]

The `include` commands do not affect this numbering, as David noted.  If I put these edits into the multi-file code you posted, the figure numbering is the same. 
So, using the second version (with `@ppsavesec` and no `\chapter{..}` added after `\begin{appendices}`) I get this from your files:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Interesting that I compiled your code and it works fine. But adding \usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}A}}

...... to my preamble did not seem to work. Maybe I have some incompatibility .

Comment: If I add `\chapter{appendix}` at the beginning of your appendix, after `\begin{appendices}`, I seem to get the desired answer (placing my two lines of code at the end of your preamble).

Comment: Okay. The reason why it is not working is due to the way I am building my file (using includes). I had removed them following @David Carlisle comment, but they seem to matter. So I reverted back.

Comment: Just added \chapter{appendix}, it did not work, once I have the includes above.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. It seems that what David above told me (which made sense at the time) to remove the includes from my main LaTex code, actually has an impact on the answer.

Comment: Yes, I was able to compile the code you'd posted based on David's advice (a single file w/o include), with the edits I mentioned in my first comment above.  Give it a whirl.

Comment: I managed to do that. Thank you :). The issue now is why w/ the includes it doesn;t work ... I will keep scratching my head trying to figure that one out.

Comment: Great!  If this solved the problem, please click to accept the answer.  :-)

Comment: That's the issue. It did not solve them problem (not once you use the code I am using above with \include)

Comment: See edits and comments in revised answer.